# Electric Potential along $x$-axis because of 2 charged parallel planes

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, capacitance

I'll get to the point. I know how to find the expression for the electric field inside two charged parallel planes, and I understand how I can then use that information to find the electric potential in that same region.

But what about the exterior? that is, the values of $x$ outside the region between the 2 planes. I know $E=0$ , so $V$ must be a constant, right? Furthermore, I was thinking since $V$ is a continuous function along the $\mathrm{x-axis}$, $V$ could be equal to the value of the potential on both planes, as to maintain the continuity, but if that were the case, then $V$ would never "decline" no matter the value of $x$, and that doesn't seem right.

I hope the explanation didn't sound confusing, thanks in advance to anyone that would like to help.

Comment: I am really not sure what is your doubt here, you are correct in saying that potential due to to infinite parallel plates is constant on the exterior and is equal to the potential of each plates.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you! That's what I thought would happen, I just wasn't 100% sure about it. It still kinda "bothers" me that outside the parallel plates the potential remains constant and doesn't decay in some way proportional to 1/x or 1/x^2 or something else, but I'm glad I was right at least.

Comment: Its all because you have assumed them to be infinite if they were finite plates, the function would be extremely complicated.